# OpenGL draw points with different colors, vertex location and vertex color in different VBOs?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, vbo

I would like to draw different points with different colors. I put the vertex location data and color data in different VBOs, such as below:

Here is my C++ code:

```
    m_Points.push_back(glm::vec3(4, 0, 0));
    m_Points.push_back(glm::vec3(0, 2, 0));
    m_Points.push_back(glm::vec3(0, 0, 3));
    m_Points.push_back(glm::vec3(0, 0, 6));

    m_Colors.push_back(glm::vec3(0, 1.0, 0));
    m_Colors.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0, 0, 0));
    m_Colors.push_back(glm::vec3(0, 0, 1.0));
    m_Colors.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0));

    glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);


    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

    // the first VBO, it is the coordinates
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * sizeof(m_Points), &m_Points[0][0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    // the second VBO, the color
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO_Color);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO_Color);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * sizeof(m_Colors), &m_Colors[0][0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // in file axis.vs, there is a statement
    // layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex;
    // the first argument 0 means (location = 0)
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,                 // location = 0 in vertics shader file
                          3,                 // the position has X,Y,Z 3 elements
                          GL_FLOAT,          // element type
                          GL_FALSE,          // do not normalize
                          sizeof(glm::vec3), // Stride
                          (void *) nullptr); // an offset of into the array, it is 0


    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    // in file axis.vs, there is a statement
    // layout (location = 1) in vec3 vertex;
    // the first argument 1 means (location = 1)
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,                 // location = 1 in vertics shader file
                          3,                 // the position has R,G,B 3 elements
                          GL_FLOAT,          // element type
                          GL_FALSE,          // do not normalize
                          sizeof(glm::vec3), // Stride
                          (void *) nullptr); // an offset of into the array, it is 0


    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Both the m_Points and m_Colors are some kind of `std::vector<glm::vec3>`

Here is my vertex shader and frame shader:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

out vec3 ObjectColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
    ObjectColor = color;

}
```

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 ObjectColor;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(ObjectColor, 1.0f);
}
```

The draw code looks like below:

```
    shader.use();
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, m_Points.size());
```

But I would like to add some points dynamically by `AddPoint()` function, so here is the code to add both vertex and color element in the vectors:

```
void AddPoint() 
{
    glm::vec3 p(5.0, 6.0, 0.0);    
    m_Points.push_back(p);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * m_Points.size(), &m_Points[0][0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glm::vec3 b(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    m_Colors.push_back(b);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO_Color);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * m_Colors.size(), &m_Colors[0][0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
```

The problem is: the initial 4 points shows correctly with 4 different colors, but the AddPoint() never works, I don't see any new points added and rendered.

I know that if I put the vertex location in a single VBO,

such as:

The date array could be:

```
x, y, z, r, g, b
x, y, z, r, g, b
x, y, z, r, g, b
x, y, z, r, g, b
```

it works without any issue.

But why it does not work if I put the location and color in different VBOs?

Any ideas? Thanks.

This question([c++ - Storing different vertex attributes in different VBO's - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223623/storing-different-vertex-attributes-in-different-vbos)) is related, but I still don't know why my problem still happens.

**EDIT**
Rabbid76 point out that `glVertexAttribPointer()` function only attach(copy) data from the previous bond VBO by `glBindBuffer`. Which suggest that I can't put the vertex location array and vertex color array in different VBOs?

**EDIT2**
Is my `AddPoint()` function wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)  associated the buffer object, which is bound to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target, to the specified attribute. The specification is stored in the state vector of the current [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).
The proper buffer object has to be bound by [`glBindBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml), before [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is invoked:

```cpp
// the first VBO, it is the coordinates
glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * sizeof(m_Points), &m_Points[0][0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

// the second VBO, the color
glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO_Color);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO_Color);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * sizeof(m_Colors), &m_Colors[0][0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO); // <--- bind `m_VBO`

glVertexAttribPointer(0,                 // location = 0 in vertics shader file
                      3,                 // the position has X,Y,Z 3 elements
                      GL_FLOAT,          // element type
                      GL_FALSE,          // do not normalize
                      sizeof(glm::vec3), // Stride

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO_Color); // <--- bind `m_VBO_Color`

glVertexAttribPointer(1,                 // location = 1 in vertics shader file
                      3,                 // the position has R,G,B 3 elements
                      GL_FLOAT,          // element type
                      GL_FALSE,          // do not normalize
                      sizeof(glm::vec3), // Stride
                      (void *) nullptr); // an offset of into the array, it is 0
```

Comment: after reading your comments and answer several times, I understand now. You are right! I now understand that the `location` in the vertex shader can reference to different VBOs, in my example, the location 0 is point to the `m_VBO`, while location 1 is point to `m_VBO_Color`. The problem here is I do not bind the correct VBO before the `glVertexAttribPointer` function call. So, you answer did solve my problem. Thanks.